# DependencyProperty doesnt pass Value after ValidateValueCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a library (WpfLibrary) with a custom control in it (MyControl), that control also have a default style (Themes\Generic.xaml).
The custom controls works fine, and the default style is applied correctly. The problem is with dependency property inside MyControl, that dependency property is a type of List, and it cannot be set from default style (Themes\Generic.xaml). Below I am posting code for MyControl, you can see I am setting dependency property in ctor. Thats needed because I cannot set in function DependencyProperty.Register (The list will be shared between multiple instances of MyControl). And if I will not set a new List, and leave a null then the users will get null exception accessing null dependency property.

```
public class MyControl : FrameworkElement
{
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        // Setting the default value of the dependency property.
        // I need that set, otherwise users of MyControl will get null exception
        Objects = new List<object>();
    }


    public List<object> Objects
    {
        get { return (List<object>)GetValue(ObjectsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ObjectsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Objects), typeof(List<object>), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, ObjectsChanged, ObjectsCoerceValue), ObjectsValidateValue);

    // Both the ctor and default style Lists are beeing passed here
    private static bool ObjectsValidateValue(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Only the ctor List is passed here
    private static object ObjectsCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return baseValue;
    }

    // Only the ctor List is passed here
    private static void ObjectsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

As I said, there are 2 places where I set the List Objects property, the second is in the default style (Themes\Generic.xaml).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">        
    <Setter Property="Objects">
        <Setter.Value>
            <local:ObjectsCollection>
                <TextBlock />
                <TextBlock />
                <TextBlock />
            </local:ObjectsCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The collection with 3 elements, is only invoked to ValidateValueCallback, but doesnt pass that point. CoarceValueCallback and PropertyChangedCallback are not beeing called with 3 element list. This also means, the property value stays as empty List Objects.
note: The local:ObjectsCollection from default style, is a simple class that inherits from List.
I am posting the whole project, but there is not much. I've tried many things, and searched 50% of google :P Couldnt find the answer,
How to set collection from default style (Themes\Generic.xaml).
[WpfApplication15.7z](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xf_Y8Tyad1EtDJMyaNmMIZ39JCGdvskR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Replace `Objects = new List<object>();` with `SetCurrentValue(ObjectsProperty, new List<object>());`

Comment: It workes, Thank you :3